# Is there a way to delete single imported contact from people hub in Outlook.com?

Tags: contacts, import, outlook.com

The title says it all.

[Outlook.com](http://www.outlook.com/) has the option to import contacts from several sources. However, I would like to delete some people which were imported from Facebook. Is there a way to delete people from contact lists, in the Outlook itself, which were imported from Facebook (or any other external source)? Deleting them on Facebook itself is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

> Outlook’s “People” feature lets you integrate contacts from Facebook, Google and Twitter, as well as from other sites and sources.
>
> Note that I said “integrate,” not import. The difference is that when you “connect” to the social services, to use Microsoft’s term, it doesn’t really import them. In other words, it doesn’t copy the address book. It merely points to it.
>
> If you want to delete a contact “imported” from Facebook, for example, you can’t do it from Outlook.com. You have to do it from Facebook. Only contacts created in the Outlook.com “People” area can be deleted from Outlook.com.

[Source](http://www.datamation.com/applications/why-the-people-feature-of-outlook.com-is-contacts-done-right.html).

<del>I haven’t imported any contacts so I don’t know if they behave differently (I assume they shouldn’t), but can’t you just delete the respective contact(s)? Just select it/them from the left-side list and a delete button will appear in the upper menu.</del>

[image]

Comment: Delete option is not available for imported contact.. me to have the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no.

The fact is, Microsoft clearly didn't think about this enough. I now have celebs that I follow on Twitter in my contacts list - what a terrible idea. I can't unlink Twitter either because I need it for my Windows Phone. They are not really "contacts" are they, Microsoft?